# python TKinter 'int'/'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Tags: python, tkinter

I know this question is asked a lot but i cant seem to get my code to work.

As a projected i'm trying to build a simple calculator. But i'm kind of stuck. Here is my code.

```
 import Tkinter as tk
import tkMessageBox

top = tk.Tk()

def helloCallBack(x):
   counter = 0    
   counter.append(x)
   tkMessageBox.showinfo("result", counter)

one = tk.Button (top, text = "1", command = lambda: helloCallBack(1))
two =  tk.Button (top, text = "2", command = lambda: helloCallBack(2))
three = tk.Button (top, text = "3", command = lambda: helloCallBack(3))
four = tk.Button (top, text = "4", command = lambda: helloCallBack(4))
five = tk.Button (top, text = "5", command = lambda: helloCallBack(5))
six = tk.Button (top, text = "6", command = lambda: helloCallBack(6))
seven = tk.Button (top, text = "7", command = lambda: helloCallBack(7))
eight = tk.Button (top, text = "8", command = lambda: helloCallBack(8))
nine = tk.Button (top, text = "9", command = lambda: helloCallBack(9))
zero = tk.Button (top, text = "9", command = lambda: helloCallBack(0))

one.pack()
two.pack()
three.pack()
four.pack()
five.pack()
six.pack()
seven.pack()
eight.pack()
nine.pack()
zero.pack()

top.mainloop()
```

i'm currently getting the 'int' object has no attribute 'append'

does this mean that you can't use the append command with numbers?

if so how would it be possible to make it so if i press one of the buttons it adds that number to the counter so if you press button one, two, five you would get 0125 i've also tried doing this with

```
counter = ""
```

but that just gives the same error but with 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

i'm new to python and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: the `append` function is for lists. try `counter += x`

Comment: Mb try to use `counter = 0 counter += str(x)` instead of .append. It should work, because we predefine it's type and concatenate strings, not integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does this mean that you can't use the append command with numbers?

Yes, that is exactly what it means.

> if so how would it be possible to make it so if i press one of the buttons it adds that number to the counter so if you press button one, two, five you would get 0125

You solve this by making `counter` a string. Leave it as a string until the moment you need it to be an integer, at which point you can do the conversion.

Though, strings don't have an `append` method either. To append to a string you can use `+=`, as in:

```
counter += x
```

Though, that requires that `x` be a string, too. The simple solution to that is to pass in a string rather than a number:

```
one = tk.Button (..., command = lambda: helloCallBack("1"))
two = tk.Button (..., command = lambda: helloCallBack("2"))
...
```

Comment: Thanks this work great. I also needed to change the counter variable to being a global one as well and move it out of the function, other wise it kept resetting to just the number pressed thanks.